# .htaccess disallow RewriteUrl from dictories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Now my css is located at: */files/style.css*
and my admin panel is located at: */admin/index.php*

When i go to this file it would show me: */index.php?cat=files&page=style.css* and */index.php?cat=admin&page=index.php*

**How can I solve this?**
(Maybe to disallow that to the maps: /files and /admin, but I don't know how..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(files|admin)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

The condition line tells Apache to skip the rewrite if requested URL starts with `/files/` or `/admin/`.